# Boolean modifier applying, making holes in one object to connect it later to another /3d printing/

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects, 3d-printing

I have a problem with a Boolean modifier. I’m making a board game asset – stables in Blender v.2.82.
[image]

The building is made by two parts – fundament
[image]

And roof
[image]

Initially there was one only one object. I found a company to print it, but there were some problems and they suggested me to separate it and print two objects which can be connect after that.
I did’t comply that the object enter into each other.

[image]

I made some projects so far and when I wanted to connect some objects /or made holes/ used Boolean modifier.
After made the fundament object active went to modifiers chose Boolean.
[image]
[image]

On operation menu choose “Diffrence”, on object menu choose the other element /roof/, hit the apply button and then everything brokes.

[image]
[image]

Don’t know how to fix it.  I just want to make holes in the roof, so when the two parts are printed I can connect them and make one building. Before using the Boolean modifier recalculated normals, scaled the object. I don’t know what to do. Please help.

Comment: Download newer version of blender with new boolean solved "Exact" it might helps https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html or just search for Flat Shading in object mode if the only one issue is weird shading.